# Typo3 RealURL tx_news 403 error on detail page with banner link

Tags: typo3, banner, realurl, tx-news

I have problems with my RealURL Configuration and can't find a solution. I have included banners in my site, but on the news detail pages the link does not work, creating a 403 error. So there has to be something wrong with my RealURL configuration:

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                ),
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                'expireDays' => 180,
            )
        )
    ),
    '18' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
```

The link when clicking on the banner looks like this:
/detail/?type=9002&tx_sfbanners_pi1[banner]=4&tx_sfbanners_pi1[action]=click&tx_sfbanners_pi1[controller]=Banner&cHash=5ab32cd1edb0529752985d5e30dfd8be

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of EXT:news are missing and need to be added when you create the link of the banner

Comment: Can you please give me an example for this?